# Generate a table based on multiple tables from database in python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

So basically I am doing coursework for my uni about covid vaccination program. So for storing data I settled on mysqlite3 as I have experience in using it. Right now, I am having a problem with generating a list of confirmed appointments. It's not that I cant generate an appointment table, what I am trying to do is that I want my generated table to have *name* instead of *icpatient* and *name* of the centre* instead of *idcentre*. How do I solve this problem

*appointment*

| idappointment | icpatient | idcentre | date | time | slotsremaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 561203089865 | 2 | 5/12/2021 | 15:00 | 59 |

*centres*

| idcentre | name | address | postcodecentre | slot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kl Central | 50470 Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur | 50470 | 50 |
| 2 | Spice Centre | 108C, Jalan Tun Dr Awang, Bayan Baru, 11900 Bayan Lepas, Pulau Pinang | 11900 | 60 |
| 3 | Kulim Hospital | Jalan Hospital, Kampung Chabang Tiga, 09000 Kulim, Kedah | 09000 | 30 |

*patients*

| icpatient | name | password |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 990329071234 | James Bond | Nightfire007 |
| 561203089865 | Subramaniam | Subramaniam1956 |

I got not python coding for this part as I am struggling to think of a right method to approach this problem..
I will attach the db file here

I use python3 and sqlite3

covid.db - > https://www.mediafire.com/file/1y6gxbfyqrlvwgc/covid.db/file

Comment: This is an SQL issue, not a Python issue.  You need to learn about JOINs.  `SELECT p.name AS patient, c.name AS center, a.date, a.time FROM appointment a INNER JOIN centres c ON a.idcentre=c.idcentre INNER JOIN patients p ON a.icpatient=p.idpatient;`

Comment: @TimRoberts yeap i learnt it today xD tq!